# What are the official Ubuntu Derivatives?

Tags: derivatives

What are the official Ubuntu derivatives? How many are there?

Answer (score 7):

There are eight official derivatives. They are:

- [Kubuntu](http://www.kubuntu.org/)
- [Xubuntu](http://www.xubuntu.org/)
- [Edubuntu](http://www.edubuntu.org/)
- [Ubuntu GNOME](http://ubuntugnome.org/)
- [UbuntuKylin](http://www.ubuntukylin.com/)
- [Lubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu)
- [Mythbuntu](http://www.mythbuntu.org/)
- [Ubuntu Studio](http://ubuntustudio.org/)

See the [Ubuntu derivatives](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/derivatives) page.